AWS::RDS::DBProxyTargetGroup unavailable
I wrote a stack containing an RDS Database, proxy and Target group but seem to run into a weird issue when deploying it. When opening the rdsproxy it says the database is unavailable in the Target group section. If i then in the rds proxy (aws GUI) press Actions -> Modify (In this view i don't touch anything) I just click modify at the end of the page. After reload it says available and everything works.
Here is the cloudformation code, is this a bug or have I messed up something?


  rDBProxy:
    DependsOn:
      - rRDSDBInstance
      - rDBProxyRole
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBProxy
    Properties:
      DBProxyName: MyDBProxy
      EngineFamily: POSTGRESQL
      RequireTLS: false
      RoleArn: !GetAtt rDBProxyRole.Arn
      Auth:
        - AuthScheme: "SECRETS"
          ClientPasswordAuthType: "POSTGRES_MD5"
          IAMAuth: "DISABLED"
          SecretArn: !Sub "${rPostgreSQLSecret}"
      VpcSecurityGroupIds:
        - Ref: pRDSDBProxySecurityGroup
      VpcSubnetIds:
        - Ref: pPrivateSubnet1
        - Ref: pPrivateSubnet2

  rTargetGroupRDS:
    DependsOn:
      - rDBProxy
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBProxyTargetGroup
    Properties: 
      DBInstanceIdentifiers:
        - !Ref rRDSDBInstance
      DBProxyName: !Ref rDBProxy
      TargetGroupName: default




Turns out this is a non issue. In time everything is up and running it just takes a little bit of extra time.
